# What is the significance of shooting porn film for An American Werewolf in London?

Tags: analysis, directors, adult-movies, an-american-werewolf-in-london

Many sources like [this](http://mentalfloss.com/article/84739/15-facts-about-american-werewolf-london) say that :

> Landis shot the porn film within the film.

But why did director make a porn film for *An American Werewolf in London*? What is the significance of going like that? Why not pick any existing porn film? And why to even have a porn film in that scene?

Comment: _See you next Wednesday_ (the name of the porn film) is a recurring theme in Director John Landis movies.  Just an FYI :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After [steelersquirrel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83720/what-is-the-significance-of-shooting-porn-film-for-an-american-werewolf-in-londo#comment141422_83720)'s comment I got to know that [See You Next Wednesday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/See_You_Next_Wednesday) is a recurring gag in John Landis' films:

> See You Next Wednesday is a recurring gag in most of the films directed by John Landis, usually referring to a fictional film that is rarely seen and never in its entirety. Each instance of See You Next Wednesday in Landis's films seems to be a completely different film.

But [this blog](http://www.seeyounextwednesday.com/blog/about/) present very detailed analysis of the significance of the film:

> The trademark trivia often mentioned in Landis directed films, the inclusion in some form of the phrase “See you next Wednesday” is a reference to a line in the Stanley Kubrick film ‘2001: A Space Odyssey’ where astronaut Frank Poole watches a video sent to him by his wife and father on the occasion of his birthday. At the end of the video his wife says, “See you next Wednesday!” an obvious reference to their next available time to transmit a message to the distant space craft bound for Jupiter, though since Frank is killed within the next day or two by HAL, it is perhaps meant as an ironic trademark since it seems to occur in Landis films when characters are in great danger.

Same happen in *An American Werewolf in London* too, where David meet his tragic fate just after seeing *See You Next Wednesday*. Even before that a character died in subway when he pass by the poster of the film:

[image]

Comment: I was always under the impression they were all a play on the See You Next Tuesday insult...

Answer (score 4):

Probably because of legal reasons and Directors Guild of America rules. The member of the guild cannot "share" the screen time with a non-union director (That's why Robert Rodriquez needed to give up his membership to make Sin-City). And finding an English porn made by a member of DGoA was probably more time and money consuming then making their own short.

In the source you provided here is a quote of Landis that he wanted character to go to the cinema in that particular spot because they showed cartoons. But many years later it changed to porn. So the movie changed but his script still stated that character goes to cinema in this particular place. So to be time and place specific Landis made a porn.

Also because of the different rating in UK and US if they used real porn they could get an X in the US.

Comment: any source for this claims?

Comment: @AnkitSharma In the third paragraph you can read about union laws regarding "one director per film" http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2005/04/why_not_quit_the_directors_guild.html

Comment: It will be better if you can mention it in your answer itself